# Is sp_stoppublication_snapshot considered a undocumented procedure or is my searching just bad?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-agent

I am trying to start and stop the replication snapshot via t-sql. I found [`sp_startpublication_snapshot`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176026(v=sql.105).aspx), and doing a trace while hitting the stop on the snapshot from inside SSMS I see it calls `sp_stoppublication_snapshot` however I don't see any documentation at all on the procedure.

Is this considered a "Undocumented procedure", I thought they all started with `sp_MS...`?

If this is a undocumented procedure is there a better way to stop the snapshot agent?

I did look in to [`sp_stop_job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182793(v=sql.100).aspx), the only thing that makes me hesitant to just use it is the remark in the documentation of

> sp_stop_job should be used only in extreme circumstances if the job contains steps of type CmdExec or PowerShell.

I assume sense the job only has two "Transact-SQL script" type steps and a "Replication Snapshot" type step it would be safe to call, is that correct? Does `sp_stoppublication_snapshot` do anything extra that calling `sp_stop_job` on the job would not do?

If I want to write scripts that is safe to use on Sql2008 through Sql2016+ and up what would be the best approach to do?